# How to check whether a char is digit or not in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I need to check if a char is digit or not.

```
NSString *strTest=@"Test55";
char c =[strTest characterAtIndex:4];
```

I need to find out if 'c' is a digit or not. How can I implement this check in Objective-C?

Comment: Careful, `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, not a `char`. Truncation such as this could lead to false positives if you deal with non-ASCII text.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In standard C there is a function `int isdigit( int ch );` defined in "ctype.h". It will return nonzero (TRUE) if  ch is a digit.

Also you can check it manually:

```
if(c>='0' && c<='9')
{
  //c is digit
}
```

Comment: Thnx alot...

I have one question??
How to convert the unichar to int?
I just tried the following
int ivalue=[[NSNumber numberWithChar:cChar] intValue];

Is it correct??

Comment: @syam: you do not need to jump through that many hoops. You should be able to convert `unichar` to `int` by  doing `int ivalue = cChar;`

Comment: What if they're Japanese numerals '零'-'九'?

Comment: I think `isdigit()` is probably better, just because it's easier to read... although maybe using that function masks the fact that it won't handle non-ASCII characters that are digits.

Answer (score 31):

**Note**: The return value for `characterAtIndex:` is not a `char`, but a `unichar`. So casting like this can be dangerous...

An alternative code would be:

```
NSString *strTest = @"Test55";
unichar c = [strTest characterAtIndex:4];
NSCharacterSet *numericSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
if ([numericSet characterIsMember:c]) {
    NSLog(@"Congrats, it is a number...");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a C function called [isdigit](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/isdigit.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite simple:

```
isdigit([YOUR_STRING characterAtIndex:YOUR_POS])
```

Comment: I went with this answer, but only because all I want is 0-9 (because I'm dealing with a programming language, not user facing languages.) If I were dealing with user facing languages, I'd probably want to use the `decimalDigitCharacterSet` solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2271360/901641

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check `NSCharacterSet` class reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of writing a generic function like the following for this:

```
BOOL isNumericI(NSString *s)
{
   NSUInteger len = [s length];
   NSUInteger i;
   BOOL status = NO;

   for(i=0; i < len; i++)
   {
       unichar singlechar = [s characterAtIndex: i];
       if ( (singlechar == ' ') && (!status) )
       {
         continue;
       }
       if ( ( singlechar == '+' ||
              singlechar == '-' ) && (!status) ) { status=YES; continue; }
       if ( ( singlechar >= '0' ) &&
            ( singlechar <= '9' ) )
       {
          status = YES;
       } else {
          return NO;
       }
   }
   return (i == len) && status;
}
```

Comment: This function does not do what the OP asked for. Additionally, an `NSScanner` will relieve you of much of the effort your function puts forth.